# Is there an alternative to "exit" in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a synchronize powershell script that syncronizes 1 cube on two different servers.

i have a flag set for each of the two servers, where three scenarios can happen:

> 1: BOTH servers TRUE
>
> 2: BOTH servers FALSE
>
> 3: 1 server TRUE, the other server FALSE

scenario one exit code is `0` (successful syncing)

scenario two exit code is `1` (failed syncing)

but for scenario 3, if one server is set to false, exit would be 1 for failed, but the script SHOULD continue running because the other server is available to sync on, with an exit code of 0 for success.

the problem with exit is it exits the remainder of the script when its called. I would like an alternative to this exit mechanism to cover scenario 3. I have found the closest thing is this:

```
[ $PS1 ] && return || exit;
```

or

```
[ -v PS1 ] && return || exit
```

but i am unsure how to pass a code there (0 or 1), let alone i received errors that the command is not recognized anyways.

> Missing type name after '['.
>
> The token '||' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
>
> The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.

The reason I need exit codes is because they are passed back to the batch file as such:

```
    if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 GOTO :error
GOTO :end
:error
REM echo Exit Code: %ERRORLEVEL%
REM echo Failed!

EXIT /B %ErrorLevel%
:end
REM echo Exit Code: %ERRORLEVEL%
REM echo Success!
```

which third party automation (autosys) depends on to reflect status.

Comment: I know on batch it's `goto :EOF` but I'm unsure for powershell.

Comment: Post an [MCVE].

Comment: @jwdonahue uh....what more would you like to see in my post, sir? I literally have mastered exactly the way questions need be asked on SO. I have already spent almost an hour everytime formatting and reviewing the thread countless times before posting. I despise counterproductive ”downvotes” that literally dont even help answer the question. If you have a suggestion/clear example of what exactly you want seen in the thread, tell me. Dont post ambiguous comments that literally contribute nothing to help resolve the problem.

Comment: @Cataster, are you claiming that you have posted a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example of the PowerShell script in question? Did you follow the link I provided and read it?

Comment: @Cataster, only trying to help here. I am the one who flagged this question for Jeremy to take a look at it, because I wasn't sure I could answer it myself.

Comment: @jwdonahue the thing is, my powershell script is too long and its irrelevant to the context. I have posted a question before that included the script but it just confused people. So ever since then I have been posting only information that is relevant. My question here is straight forward: if there is an alternative to exit code. That's it. The powershell code serves no purpose to be pasted here unless to cause massive confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there doesnt seem to be an alternative (an exit code passed without exiting), I have instead used a conditional incremental, in which

```
if ($i -eq 1) # 1 indicates that it ran successfully on just one server (scenario3)
{exit 0} # 0 for success

elseif ($i -gt 1) #if scenario 2 was the case, provide exit 1 for failure on BOTH servers
{ exit 1 }

else {exit 0} #for scenario 1
```

all my scenarios are now working as intended, solving the exit code issue

Answer (score 2):

Check out this article. It covers the topic in depth:

https://weblogs.asp.net/soever/returning-an-exit-code-from-a-powershell-script

I don’t want to take away from Serge’s answer (it is somewhat exhaustive), but as a hint, his first conclusion is:

“Don’t use exit to return a value from PowerShell code, but use the following function:

```
function ExitWithCode 
{ 
  param 
  ( 
      $exitcode 
  )
  $host.SetShouldExit($exitcode) 
  exit 
}
```

Comment: I have taken a look at this blog post before posting this thread, but I dint think it serves what I'm looking for. It's still an exit regardless. I was looking for something that simply returns a code # (0, 1) that is recognized by %errorlevel% in batch file to pass back to autosys, as mentioned in my question

Comment: Ok, so you want to pass an exit code without exiting the script?

Comment: @Moss basically yes